# calling jquery function from a dropdown list

Tags: jquery

I have the following dropdown list box:

```
      <select name="DDLConditional1" size="1">
            <option selected="selected">is equal to</option>
            <option>begins with</option>
            <option onclick="ShowBetween();">is between</option>
            <option>is not equal to</option>
            <option>is greater than</option>
            <option>is less than</option>
        </select>
```

I want to show() a textbox and a label based on someone selecting the "is between" option of the dropdown list.
I have multiples of these dropdowns and all of them will have to do the same thing. In other words I have
DDLConditional1 2 3 4... infinite. I've already been able to make the button work that appends new conditionals.

Comment: What are you asking? How to make the textbox and label appear? How to dynamically add new dropdown? How to make an event fire from every dropdown?

Comment: What's your question? Are you having a specific problem implementing this?

Comment: @Deano - If you're confused about all the down-votes on the answers given, just be aware that they're all presumably from one user who is even more confused.

Comment: I'm gonna upvote all your answers to avoid this stupid confusion.

Comment: @Marko - I've got yours covered too. :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd get rid of the inline handler assignment, and use jQuery to manage your handler.

It sounds like the `<select>` elements are being dynamically added to the DOM, so this uses [jQuery's `.live()` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to handle those dynamic elements.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/GPMmJ/

```
$(function() {
    $('select[name^=DDLConditional]').live('change', function() {
        if( $(this).val() === 'is between') {
            alert('is between was selected');
        }
    });
});
```

Any time a `<select>` that has a name that [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `DDLConditional` is added to the page, the `change` handler will work automatically. It gets the value of what was selected using [jQuery's `.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/), and checks to see if it is the `in between` one.

Comment: You want 'click', not 'change'. This won't work in 1.3.2 and ie.

Comment: @Stefan - So `jQuery 1.3.2` is being used here? That's why you down-voted me? Because I really don't see that anywhere in the question.

Comment: @Stefan, You're an idiot. It DOES work in IE6/7/8 and the OP never mentioned jQuery 1.3.2. http://jsfiddle.net/JhBdm/. Now give me my vote back :)

Comment: @patrick wouldn't `val()` simply return a blank string? I think you want the `text()` of the option :)

Comment: @Vivin - Actually, no. When there isn't a value assigned to the `<option>`, the `value` property defaults to the text content. The only issue is that the `value` property for IE6 doesn't do this, but jQuery's `.val()` corrects it. :o)

Comment: He really should use the `value` attribute versus relying on the `<option>` text, but to each their own.  Also: patrick's last comment.

Comment: @patrick @mway oh! I did not know that! Learned something new today :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use jQuery throughout with the `onChange` event instead of `onClick`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    

   jQuery("select[name^=DDLConditional]").live("change", function() {
      if(jQuery("option:selected", this).text() === "is between") {
         //display the textbox and label
      }
   });
});
```

This code runs after the page has loaded. It looks for all `select` elements whose names start with `DDLConditional`. It then uses `live` (so that even future elements that could be added dynamically are considered) to bind a handler to the `change` event.

Comment: @Stefan What are you talking about? Where does jQuery 1.3.2 and IE even come into this? That's why you downvoted? Please don't downvote without valid reason.

Comment: Apparently @Stefan thinks we're not allowed to give answers that aren't compatible all the way back to... what... `jQuery version 1`?

Comment: I've flagged his comments as noise.

Comment: @patrick. Apparently. I wish people would spell out their disagreement. This kind of mass downvoting is completely unhelpful; even seems spiteful.

Comment: Vivin - Agreed. Seems especially spiteful since @Stefan didn't stick around to enter into any discussion. More like a hit 'n run.

Answer (score 1):

Yep sure thing, just wrap the `<select>` in a div and you can easily append a textbox using jQuery. Something like:

```
<div class="conditional>
    <select name="DDLConditional1" size="1">
        ...
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // store our select as a jQuery object
        var $select = $(".conditional select");
        $select.change(function() {
            // get our parent (the div)
            var $wrapper = $(this).closest(".conditional");

            // if the selected option's text is "in between"
            if($("option:selected", this).text() == "is between") {
                // append a textbox
                var $newTextbox = $("<input type='text' />");
                $newTextbox.css('color', 'red'); //perhaps set some CSS properties?
                $wrapper.append($newTextbox);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JhBdm/) that works in IE 7/8, Firefox, Chrome and Safari.**

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `onclick` - you want to use the `onchange` of the `<select>`, where you'll test its current value to see if it's what you want.

Comment: I don't recall anything about 1.3.2, and I also don't recall IE complaining about `onchange`.  Next time you disagree with a group of answers, post a better solution instead of being unhelpful.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your prompt responses. The ".live" solution works for me, and on IE8. My next challenge is to show two dynamically created and enumerated controls (one label and one text box) based on the "is between" being selected.